# how to prepare accessible data for paint method

Tags: java

I have problem with script below - i dont know  how to move to the next point. This part of script will show me coordinates from my XML (input.xml) file. But I would like to draw line (coordinates x0,y0,x1,y1) - obtained from my input I can see them if i return xList and yList, but i really dont know how to continue, how to prepare them to be accesssible for a paint method (graphics g).

thanks

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException
    {

```
    if (xele)
    {
        System.out.println("X value : " + new String(ch, start, length));
        xele = false;
        xList.add(Integer.parseInt(new String(ch, start, length)));
    }

    if (yele)
    {
        System.out.println("Y value : " + new String(ch, start, length));
        yele = false;
        yList.add(Integer.parseInt(new String(ch, start, length)));
    }
}

public List<Integer> getXList()
{
    return xList;

}

public List<Integer> getYList()
{
    return yList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xList` and `yList` should be static - then they will be accessible  with  `ClassName.xList.get` and `ClassName.yList.get`